# Referenced model not showing in edit page when using populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

In my application, I have two models - Book and Genre. I referenced the Genre model from the Book model using `Schema.Types.ObjectId`. So this is how my models look like:

Book model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const bookSchema = Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter a book name'
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  genre: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre'
  }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
```

Genre model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const genreSchema = Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter a Genre name'
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema)
```

On the book edit page, I want to be able to show the genres available and check the ones already saved in that particular book.

Here is what I have for my routes:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  const book = Book.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
  .populate({
    path: 'genre',
    model: 'Genre',
    populate: {
      path: 'genre',
      model: 'Book'
    }
  })
  .exec()
    .then((book) => {
      const genres = Genre.find({ 'genre': req.params.id })
      res.render('editBook', { book, genres })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err
    })
})

router.post('/edit/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty()
  req.checkBody('description', 'Description is required').notEmpty()
  req.checkBody('category', 'Category is required').notEmpty

  const errors = req.validationErrors()

  if (errors) {
    console.log(errors)
    res.render('editBook', { book, errors })
  }

  const book = Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body,
  {
    new: true,
    runValidators:true
  }).exec()
  .then((book) => {
    res.redirect(`/books/edit/${book._id}`)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.send({
      'message': err
    })
  })
})
```

And the part where the genre should be displayed looks like this:

```
.form-group
          label.col-lg-2.control-label Genre
          .col-lg-10
            for genre in genres
              .checkbox
                input.checkbox(type='checkbox', name='genre', id=genre._id, value=genre._id, checked=genre.checked)
                label(for=genre._id) #{genre.name}
```

What am I possibly doing wrong? I have tried all the solutions I know but nothing has worked.

**P.S**: [mongoose-deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) plugin has not been updated for a long time. The solution I used worked fine for the show routes and can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464418/2119604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using mongose `populate` method incorrectly. `populate` returns the object which a parent and referenced model (s). In your case `book` has an array of genres (btw, it has wrong name in your schema, single instead of plural), so you don't need additional request to load genres:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  Book
    .findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    .populate('genre')
    .exec()
    .then(book => res.render('editBook', { book, genres: book.genre }))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    });
});
```